# Couldn't make pendrive boot-able using UnetBootin

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, iso, unetbootin

I've an iso file for RHEL in one of my pendrives. Now I want to first make the device bootable, so that later on I can put RHEL as a VM. Now the problem is even after following the instructions to install at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-linux-usb-from-linux/ , I still couldn't install it, and thus couldn't make it bootable.

I am still not getting the real issue. Or is there any other way of installing any such package which could make the USBs as boot-able?

EDIT : My purpose here is to install RHEL via KVM. I have Ubuntu 14.04 as of now, and I have the iso file for RHEL in a pen-drive downloaded from a different system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was infact no such issue. I somehow missed to check the file-permissions of the .iso file. Set it to exe, and then was able to boot RHEL via kvm.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. Is there enough space on the USB drive?
2. Is the USB drive mounted?

You may want to try reformatting the drive before you attempt running unetbootin **beware that this will wipe the USB Drive!**:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdx (replace x with whatever the usb drive # is)
```

Then type `d` then the `ENTER Key` This will delete the current partition. If the drive has multiple partitions, you'll need to repeat this step until all partitions are deleted.

```
Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.
```

Then add a new partition:

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-3915775, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-3915775, default 3915775): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 1.9 GiB.
```

Then 'w' to write the changes:

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Then you should be able to use unetbootin to create the bootable USB drive.

Comment: There is enough space available in the USB. Also the USB drive is mounted. I am receiving the following error : 


root@Amlan:~# sudo ./unetbootin-linux-latest
./unetbootin-linux-latest: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libsmbsharemodes0` to resolve that issue

Comment: still facing the issue. 

new error message : ./unetbootin-linux-latest: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory