# Can't access internet in KVM virtual machine running RHEL

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I have the VM running on 14.04. When I checked for network connections on 14.04 it's available.
But, the network connections are unavailable for RHEL6.5 running on my VM.

I executed iwconfig to view the availability of network connections. In 14.04 it's showing connected, but for RHEL it's not.

Earlier also I have used RHEL6 putting up as a VM on RHEL6 just to experiment. And internet worked, had no issues. Is it dependent on the OS platform on which the VM is running?

On executing `ethtool eth0`, I am seeing an output as: `link detected: no`

Inside Virtual Machine Manager I am seeing *Virtual Networks* - > *Forwarding: NAT*, but I'm not seeing the network adapter being enabled.

What could be the issue? Please help!

Comment: @karel in kvm virtual box I don't know where could I find the network adapter settings. I guess it's only available in vmware not in kvm. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: virtual box is there, and inside virtual box - > virtual networks - > forwarding NAT.. but I am not seeing anywhere the network adapter being enabled in the display.

EDIT : by virtual box I mean here the vm manager.

Comment: This is an issue with a non-Ubuntu system, it is pretty much offtopic as a result (the guest is RHEL6.5, but it worked in RHEL6, so the issue doesn't appear to be the host, but the guest VM.)

Comment: @ThomasW. May be you're correct with your point, that the issue lies with the guest VM. But I don't understand if there was no issue when the host was RHEL..then why is it happening when the host is Ubuntu?
Do common features of networking vary from OS to OS, and that too for a VM?

Comment: If the problem lies in Ubuntu, then you should give us some details about the VM configuration. By the way, it's not clear to me why you are explicitly mentioning "KVM" in your question: does networking work if you disable KVM?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini The thing is if it were Oracle Virtual Box then we could have looked in the network adapter being enabled or not.. this has earlier been suggested by karel. But using kvm you don't have any such option to check that.. I don't find it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot there exist more Virtual Box versions. FWIW, check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23985/oracle-linux-6-1-guest-on-virtualbox-4-1-cant-connect-to-network and https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/02/28/configuring-virtualbox-guests-to-access-the-internet-and-be-accessible-from-the-host/

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini In fact I gathered from Virtual Travels's comments as well as from reading [a previous question by Virtual Travels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626713/couldnt-make-pendrive-boot-able-using-unetbootin), that he was not using VirtualBox in this case, rather he was using KVM with Virtual Machine Manager as the GUI interface. I am unhappy to see that this question has been close voted as unclear after I tried to edit it to make it clearer, which is plain to see simply by reading the question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally the issue is resolved.
go to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and edit the file, enable eth0 onboot. And then run chkconfig network on . While I tried doing the same by adding a network interface at the VM app UI : Edit > Connection Details > Network Interfaces, and tried adding eth0 to the network interfaces, I kept receiving errors, and it couldn't be moved to active state. But it was achieved from the terminal. So now my question is, why was I not able to make it happen from the GUI itself?

**EDIT** : Now again, I faced the same challenge with RHEL6.0, where in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file the settings for BOOTPROTO ; and interface type were missing so entered those as BOOTPROTO=dhcp and TYPE=Ethernet and it is also working now.